# Book with female protagonist, magical academy, magic liquid / essence, ends in war

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, books-of-magic

Read this series (or may have been a massive novel, not sure) at least 15 years ago (cant recall when it was published but I dont think it was published in 2008, I think it was much older but that's just a guess, author's name), and I've listed below the things I recall about it:

- Set in a medieval-ish earth-like environment, with made-up kingdoms and cities.
- Young female protagonist wishes to go to a magic academy. She's saving up the fees but doesnt have enough.
- Think she was red-haired.  Think she might have been called Elena / Elle / something similar, but I could be completely wrong there / mixing up with other books.
- She's poor, there's something about her selling some wares in a local market to try and make money for the school fees, something about the queen / local grand lady type person who buys stuff from her, and finally helps her get in the school (though protagonist doesnt know this for a while).
- She (protagonist) has an aging dad in a cottage in the woods / forest.
- There are tribal folks who live a very quiet life (lots of herbal power etc.), and not very friendly due to historical reasons, but in the end come out to help in the final war due to the protagonist and (I think) her friend.  *To ensure no distraction, these tribal folks are a sub-plot, not the main story-line.*
- There are towers in this academy (I think one tower per area of study), and a large green area where students hang out - I recall scenes where the protagonist likes to sit under a tree when reading, relaxing etc.
- She obviously aces in the academy after usual prejudices.  I think the advanced magic uses some precious liquid that is only available in very small quantities (little bottles with stoppers)
- She meets a vagabond / thief who is your typical interesting 'bad guy' in her hometown.
- There was a lot about a bridge / bridges and other construction built with magic of the sort lost to people.
- After graduating, the protagonist travels across different cities etc., meets rulers, builds a reputation / high credibility, runs into the bad-guy chap who then turns into the love interest after some solid redemption type scenarios.
- There's some politics that ends up in a war, and she helps one side wielding magic in the war, until the final battle is to protect the academy - lots of magic in the fight.

And this is the bit where I get all fuzzy - not sure if I may be mixing up two series, but I think they're the same book:

- There's this old guy (white hair, but very spry etc.) who keeps turning up at all unlikely places in the book.  Turns out he is the last of a set of inter-dimensional travellers who came to earth a very very long time ago, and they had some very different capabilities that made the people on earth take them to be gods.  And they were all not benign, though this old guy is inherently good.  All his other peers left earth to go to another dimension, and this guy is here to make sure they dont return, as he loves earth.

Would really love it if someone recalls this series from all my rambling, I recall enjoying this series, want to share it with my daughter as well as re-read, and it's been driving me crazy for a couple of years now trying to recall the title!